# negative position utility classes not generated

Tags: tailwind-css

I am trying to use negative position utility classes like `-left-1` but they are not being generated.

I am using version 2.0.2 and checking the generated css I can see that these classes are not being generated although regular positive ones are.  The negative classes are listed on this page as a default class: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/top-right-bottom-left.

I have tried reset the config to default:

```js
module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

But it still doesn't generate the negative classes listed at top of the doc page.

Why are these classes not being generated?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example where the issue occurs?

Answer (score 7):

It should work as mentioned in the docs. Maybe your screen/viewport is hidding the negative margin with overflow-hidden or something else.

Checkout this [working model for negative left-1](https://play.tailwindcss.com/5Kcj8cl0LP)

```
<div class="relative h-32 w-32 bg-green-100 mx-auto">
  <div class="absolute inset-x-0 top-0 -left-1 h-16 bg-green-300">1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue is the class -left-1 is not generated in css.  If that class doesn't get generated no amount of html tweaking will make it work.  It has to get generated in order to be used.

Answer (score 1):

I never generated it before, but I achieved to make it work. Here are the steps that I followed.

```
npx tailwindcss-cli@latest init -p
```

I get the following version: `tailwindcss 2.0.3`, then I'm generating it with

```
npx tailwindcss-cli@latest build -c tailwind.config.js -o compiled.css
```

After looking into the compiled file, I can see that it generated all the negative inset classes like `.-inset-1` properly.

---

PS: [this playground example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/QIv5hSijPC) confirms that it is working properly, just to be sure.